# Is there a difference in speed between multiple where clauses vs one where clause with multiple parameters C# IQueryable

Tags: c#, performance, linq

My question is if there is any difference in speed between this query

```
query.Where(i => (i.FirstName.Contains(firstname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname)) &&
                                (i.LastName.Contains(secondname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondname)) &&
                                (i.DateOfOrder == date || date == default(DateTime)));
```

and this code:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
        {
            query = query.Where(i => i.FirstName.Contains(firstname));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(secondname))
        {
            query = query.Where(i => i.FirstName.Contains(firstname));
        }

        if (date!=default(DateTime))
        {
            query = query.Where(i => i.DateOfOrder==date);
        }
```

Edited, thanks for the answers.

Comment: Have you considered trying it to see if there is?

Comment: Is the 2nd one even correct?  Isn't each `query.Where` returning a different `IQueryable` (or whatever), and not modifying the original?  Either way, [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: At second section, it will check all 'if' clauses. At first section, if first section until first && is false, it wont check second section after && so it will exit, in that case first code is faster.

Comment: The second piece of code is incorrect. It needs to be `query = query.Where(...)` inside each if-statement block.

Comment: LINQ to what? EF? Objects? With EF, there should be no difference if the same SQL is generated. With objects, each Where is another iterator which does *not* mean another loop. Just one extra call per item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess second code should be like below:

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.FirstName.Contains(firstname));
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(secondname))
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.FirstName.Contains(firstname));
    }
    if (date!=default(DateTime))
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.DateOfOrder==date);
    }
```

but in any case, you may check the final sql query generated and compare them instead.

to get the sql query, you can

1. write the sql to console by calling `dbCtx.Log = Console.Out`
2. profile your sql server and see what queries come in

Comment: thanks, will definitely try.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. In any case, there is no difference. If the queries actually do the same thing, the generated SQL will be the same. And even if it's different, the optimizer will generate the same execution plan.